Return row ID # to be used in next execute() statement?
I have three tables, one master table for plant readings, whose id is the foreign key that associates multiple readings from the compressor table and the ice temperatures table. I want to get the id from the plant reading, after it is created, to use as the foreign key when inserting data into the compressors and ice tables. But the code breaks around $plant_check_id. I can't figure out why? lastInsertId() doesn't seem to be working either?
When a new plant reading is created, first step is to create a new record with a unique ID
        //create a new plant reading
        $new_plant_reading = $connection->prepare("
            INSERT INTO plant_readings (time_of_day) VALUES (:time_of_day)");

        $plant_reading = $new_plant_reading->execute(
                array(
                ':time_of_day' => $_POST["time_of_day"]
                )
            ); 

        $last_id = $connection->prepare("
            SELECT MAX(id) FROM `plant_readings`");
        $plant_check_id = $last_id->query();  
        //$plant_reading_id = intval($plant_check_id->lastInsertId());

        $statement = $connection->prepare("
            INSERT INTO compressor_readings (suction, discharge, oil_pressure, oil_temperature, water_temperature, compressor_id, plant_readings_id) VALUES (:s, :d, :op, :ot, :wt, :cid, :pid)");
        $result = $statement->execute(
            array(
                ':s'    =>   $_POST["suction1"],
                ':d'    =>   $_POST["discharge1"],
                ':op'    =>   $_POST["oil_pressure1"],
                ':ot'    =>   $_POST["oil_temperature1"],
                ':wt'    =>   $_POST["water_temperature1"],
                ':cid'    =>   1,
                ':pid' => $plant_check_id 
            )
        );


You should use the lastInsertId function as selecting max(id) from the table is not going to work correctly if you have multiple writers updating the table - you can't be sure if the id read belongs to your inserted row.
For MySQL lastInsertId returns the last insert on the connection it is called, so as long as you do it before another insert you will get the correct id, even if other inserts have happened after yours.
It might not be working for you because you are calling it on a query rather than the connection which just performed the insert.
Try this and see if you get a value:
$new_plant_reading->execute( ... );
$lastId = $new_plant_reading->lastInsertId(); // use the connection


lastInsertId() seems to be what is breaking this. I use either that or the mariaDB equivalent LAST_INSERT_ID() and the compressors readings insert will not execute, even with a hardcoded id (4). I comment out $lastId = $new_plant_reading->lastInsertId(); and it works with a hardcoded number. Even casting as an int, or intval() doesn't seem to help. Not sure if this has something to do with mariaDB?
